# Given name in PHP for input tag, when I use the name it shows warning undefined? Why this is happning even if I define name?

Tags: php, forms

1. I have declared the `isset` to check whether name is working or not but it gives the output as `FALSE`.
2. I have highlighted the lines where I'm getting the "error".
3. This is happening with every tag I have declared. I don't know why this is happening.
4. If I use `$_REQUIRE['submit']` directly it shows a warning as UNDEFINED variable.

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   $username = $_SESSION['username'];
   echo "<h1>Hello, " . $username . ".</h1>";

   if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
       session_unset();
       session_destroy();
       echo "<script> location.href='login.php' </script>";
   }

   // this is where I always get "False"
   $check = isset($_REQUEST['submit']);
   if($check)
   {
       echo "TRUE";
   }
   else
   {
       // Always I get this
       echo "FALSE";
   }


   ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <title>Home</title>
       <style>
           body{
               text-align: center;
           }
           h1{
               font-size: 100px;
               text-transform: capitalize;
           }
           button{
               height: 50px;
               width: 100px;
               background-color: lightskyblue;
               color: white;
               font-size: x-large;
               border-radius: 10px;
               font-family: monospace;
           }
           button:hover{
               cursor: pointer;
           }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p>Have a nice day.</p>
       <button type="submit" name="submit" value="20">LOGOUT</button>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```

Comment: Your submit button doesnt seem to be in a form at all

Comment: It was working after putting it in form.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works following. Consider it.

```
<?php
session_start();

// Just for test.
// $_SESSION['username'] = 'test1';

$username = isset($_SESSION['username']) ? $_SESSION['username'] : 'Nobody';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    echo "<script>location.href='login.php';</script>";
}
?>

<form>
    <h1><?php echo "Hello, " . $username ?></h1>
    <p>Have a nice day.</p>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="20">LOGOUT</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It was working after putting submit button in form.
Thank you.